# Pointer on google map

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, google-maps, c#-4.0, google-maps-api-3

I have requirement of displaying an address on a click of a button, for which i got the latitude and longitude of the desired location,

while mapping in URl
`https://maps.google.com/?ll=28.64036031970850,77.24250191970849`

like this. I don't get the desire pointer on google map Like which we get A in red pointer.
Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: create another web page and open it in new tab, that page will contain google map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Change the lat/long as per your need. 
https://maps.google.com/?q=22.917923,72.773438

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom markers for this.  Here is a snippet to get you started:

```
// Create the map
var map = new google.maps.Map($("#map-result"), mapOptions);

// Create the marker on the map
var marker = new CustomMarker(new google.maps.LatLng(pinLatitude, pinLongitude), map, searchResults[i], markerNumber);

// Add listener to react to click of marker
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
    return function () {
        // Call some function to do something
        showSelectedMarker();
    }
})(marker, i));
```

A very good example is here:

[Google Maps JS API v3 - Simple Multiple Marker Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example)

Comment: Sir i want to redirect to the google map. instead of showing in my website. so i just want to pass the url which locate my specified address.